# REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL Big Query

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have written a regex which works in Regex101, however does not work in BigQuery, I need to figure out a translation to run it in BQ.

This is the regex: `(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\;)`
This is the data: `(400.0; 10/26/2020; 12/13/2020;); (500.0; 12/21/2020; 01/31/2021;);`

This pulls out `400.0` and `500.0`.

However I receive an error

```
Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<
```

I believe it is due to the lookbehind, could anyone help?

Comment: Are you using the forward-slash character to denote the boundaries of the regular expression  `/(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\;)/` as required by BQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RE2 regex library](https://github.com/google/re2) does not support lookarounds.

In this case, you may actually remove the lookaround syntax and use

```
\((.*?);
```

Alternatively,

```
\(([^;]*);
\(([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?);
```

That is, you need to use a regex with a capturing group that matches the text you need to extract.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/db1ddR/1).

*Details*:

- `\((.*?);` - a `(` char, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, captured into Group 1, and then a `;` char
- `\(([^;]*);` - a `(`, then any zero or more chars other than `;` captured into Group 1, and then a `;`
- `\(([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?);` - a `(` char, then one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits captured into Group 1 and then a `;` char.

Comment: If I also wanted to pull out the start and end dates? I have added:

REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(IOBudgetSegment, r'\d*\/\d*\d*\/\d*') AS Dates

However this only adds them as another column, how would I add a "start date" and and "end Date?"

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Do you mean you want to extract them as separate columns? `REGEXP_EXTRACT(IOBudgetSegment, r';\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4});') AS StartDate` and `REGEXP_EXTRACT(IOBudgetSegment, r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4});\)') AS EndDate`

Comment: Exactly, I would like to have a three column table where I have one with the budget amount, then one with the start, and one with the end date.

However where both budgets have their own start and end dates.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I just needed to use REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL

Thanks!

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew is there a method for these to pull in one line, I am trying to run a SELECT DISTINCT function across this and because I have multiple rows of data in one main row it's throwing an error

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Did you try `SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(...), ', ') AS text`? Sorry, it is probably worth another question.

Comment: I have: 

SELECT 
   IOName,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(IOBudgetSegment, r'\(([^;]*);') AS BudgetSegment,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(IOBudgetSegment, r';\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4});') AS StartDate,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(IOBudgetSegment, r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4});\)') AS EndDate,FROM media-audit-platform.MailOnline_EasternAdaptations.MailOnline_EasternAdaptations_Prog_SDF_V5_AllLevelUnion